# Vue.js @keydown get key that was pressed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, keyboard, keydown

I want to use Vue.js to output which key was pressed.

This code works:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => { 
   console.log(event.key);
});
```

Something like that e.g.:

```
<div @keydown="getKey">
</div>
```

```
getKey: function(event) {
   console.log(event.key)
}
```

Comment: This does work, but in input boxes and textareas...it doesn't seem to work in divs though. Why can't you use the first example though?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you need to assign event listener to vue method:

```js
created() {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
},
beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
},
methods: {
  handleKeyDown(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. Had a lot of trubble with "$refs.something" undefined! Ur solution helped wonders!
I just moved the addEventListener to the mounted() lifecycle.